How to use dynamic fonts from local directory in iOS Widgets?
I am currently working on an iOS app where I have registered custom fonts from the local directory using CoreText within the main app. Now, I want to use these same custom fonts in a widget extension, but I am unsure if I need to register them again for the widget or if they can be reused.
Here’s a simplified version of my current FontManager class that loads and registers fonts from a local directory in the app:
import Foundation
import CoreText
import CoreGraphics
import os.log

final class FontManager {
    static let shared = FontManager()
    private var registeredFonts: Set<String> = []
    private let logger = Logger(subsystem: "com.yourapp.FontManager", category: "FontManager")
    
    private init() {
        preloadRegisteredFonts()
    }

    func loadFont(from url: URL) -> Result<String, FontLoadingError> {
        guard url.isFileURL else {
            logger.error("Invalid local URL: \(url.absoluteString)")
            return .failure(.invalidLocalURL)
        }

        do {
            let fontData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            if let postScriptName = registerFont(with: fontData) {
                return .success(postScriptName)
            } else {
                return .failure(.fontRegistrationFailed)
            }
        } catch {
            logger.error("Failed to read font data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return .failure(.dataReadFailed)
        }
    }

    private func registerFont(with fontData: Data) -> String? {
        guard let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData as CFData),
              let cgFont = CGFont(dataProvider),
              let postScriptName = cgFont.postScriptName as String? else {
            logger.error("Failed to create CGFont")
            return nil
        }

        if registeredFonts.contains(postScriptName) {
            logger.info("Font already registered: \(postScriptName)")
            return postScriptName
        }

        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        if CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(cgFont, &error) {
            registeredFonts.insert(postScriptName)
            logger.info("Successfully registered font: \(postScriptName)")
            return postScriptName
        } else {
            logger.error("Failed to register font: \(postScriptName)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    private func preloadRegisteredFonts() {
        if let availableFonts = CTFontManagerCopyAvailablePostScriptNames() as? [String] {
            registeredFonts = Set(availableFonts)
        }
    }
}

My questions are:

Do I need to register the fonts separately for the widget, or can I reuse the fonts registered in the main app?
If I need to register the fonts for the widget as well, where should I handle this within the widget's lifecycle?
Are there any specific considerations or limitations when using custom fonts located in the app's local directory in widgets?

Any guidance or best practices for handling custom fonts in widgets would be greatly appreciated!
I was hoping the fonts registered in the main app would automatically be available in the widget without having to register them again. If this isn’t possible, I expected there to be a method or place in the widget lifecycle to register these fonts dynamically.
I'm looking for the most efficient way to handle local custom fonts in a widget extension.

I don't use a FontManager like you, but what I do to use my custom fonts in my widget targets is this:
I checked the target membership of the font files for the widget and added the ones I use to the Info.plist file(Widget Plist). I also created a Font extension(Inside Widget Target) for convenience. Hope this answers.


    extension Font {
    
    static func Comforta400(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> Font {
        return Font.custom("Comfortaa-Regular", size: size)
    }
    
    static func Comforta700(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> Font {
        return Font.custom("Comfortaa-Bold", size: size)
    }
 
}

Text("widget_qr").font(.Comforta400(ofSize: 8))


This works for a few fonts, but my fonts change all the time—there may be more than 100—and I want them to support at runtime, not preconfigure it before.
